# How to access to superclass functions from a subclass object

Tags: c++

Is there a way to access superclass methods from a subclass?
I made Apple class as a subclass of Fruit class, but I can not access to setName function in Fruit class from an object of Apple class.
Could you give me any advice?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Fruit {
public:
    Fruit(string str)
    {
        cout << "Fruit class" << endl;
        name = str;
        cout << name << endl;
    }

    void setName(string str) {
        name = str;
    }
private:
    string name;
};

class Apple:Fruit {
public:
    Apple() :Fruit("apple"){
        cout << "Apple class" << endl;

    }
    void setName(string str) {
        name = str;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Apple apple;

    apple.setName("Orange");  //I can not access to setName function from apple
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `public` inheritance like this:

```
class Apple : public Fruit
```

The default visibility for `class` is `private` if it's not specified. That is why you're not able to access the `public` members of the base class because they're now private due to their `private` visibility.

Contrary to a `class`, the default visibility for a `struct` is `public` i.e.:

```cpp
struct Base {};
struct Derived : Base {}; // public inheritance
```

---

In your code, the overridden `setName()` method in the derived class is redundant as it cannot manipulate the private data member `name` directly. You'll have to use the base class method to set the `name` in your overridden method. As of now, you're not doing anything else in that method so you don't need it.

Here's your working code ([live](https://godbolt.org/z/K_vng8)):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Fruit {
public:
    Fruit(string str)
    {
        cout << "Fruit class" << endl;
        name = str;
        cout << name << endl;
    }

    void setName(string str) {
        name = str;
    }
private:
    string name;
};

class Apple : public Fruit {       // public inheritance
public:
    Apple() :Fruit("apple"){
        cout << "Apple class" << endl;
    }
    // void setName(string str) {  // Redundant!
    //     name = str;             // `name` is not accessible here!
    // }
};

int main()
{
    Apple apple;
    apple.setName("Orange");      // Accessible here
    return 0;
}
```

For more relevant information, refer to this:
[Difference between private, public, and protected inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance)

Comment: Small nitpick: private inheritance is only used by default for `class`es because `private` is the default visibility for `class` members. In `struct Apple : Fruit {};` Fruit will be a public parent of Apple.

Comment: @bitmask: Thank you for the input! I kept it focused on class as the OP's question didn't have any reference to the structs.

Comment: @bitmask: I've updated my answer regarding `struct` also. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 0):

Your `Apple` class is using **private** inheritance (the default when the *type* of inheritance is not specified), so all of `Fruit`'s `public` methods are `private` in `Apple` and thus are not accessible for `main()` to call.  You need to use **public** inheritance instead to fix that.

Also, there is no need to re-implement `setName()` in `Apple`. The inherited `setName()` from `Fruit` will suffice, once it is inherited as a public method in `Apple`.

```cpp
class Apple : public Fruit {
public:
    Apple() : Fruit("apple"){
        cout << "Apple class" << endl;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use public inheritance

```
class Apple:public Fruit
```

in class Default is Private

```
class Apple:Fruit
```

is same as

```
class Apple:private Fruit
```

You made private here, So you can not access member of Fruit by object of Apple even if it is public.

```
class Apple:public Fruit
{
public:
    Apple() :Fruit("apple")
    {
        cout << "Apple class" << endl;
    }
};
```

Or if you want it is to private use like this

```
class Apple:Fruit 
{
public:
    Apple() :Fruit("apple")
    {
        cout << "Apple class" << endl;
    }
    void setName(string str) 
    {
      Fruit::setName(str);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First, change class Apple to

```
class Apple: public Fruit
```

then, use this method

```
apple.Fruit::setname()
```

Comment: They're is no need to use `Apple.Fruit::setname()`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yeah, that's right, I just wanna show the way to get access to the superclass method through a child object.. but typed the wrong letter..